# adding a class depending on time of the day

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to my #top depending on what time it is.
I can't get the code to work properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var A = [0,1,6,7,12,13,18,19];
            var B = [2,3,8,9,14,15,20,21];
            var now = new Date();
            var hours = now.getHours();
              if (hours = A) {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('A');
            } else if (hours = B) {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('B');
            } else {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('C');
            }
        });
```

Comment: 1. `if (hours=A)` is assignment, did you mean `==`?  2. can't use `int==array` (assuming 1.), probably want `A.includes(hours)`

Comment: Hi Max, welcome and thank you to join this community! Let me give you some tips: we encourage people to write questions as clearest as possible, so I'd recommend you to include in your writting: what specific part of your code is not working? or even better: what are you getting from your code against what did you expect from it? Also remember we don't usually include any "thank you" messages in the questions (you better reserve them for the comments!). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find if an element is in an array you should use .indexOf ().

For example: `array.indexOf(something) > -1` returns `true` if `something` is in the array

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var A = [0,1,6,7,12,13,18,19];
            var B = [2,3,8,9,14,15,20,21];
            var now = new Date();
            var hours = now.getHours();
              if (A.indexOf(hours) > -1) {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('A');
            } else if (B.indexOf(hours) > -1) {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('B');
            } else {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('C');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Evik's answer you can instead use the includes function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var A = [0,1,6,7,12,13,18,19];
            var B = [2,3,8,9,14,15,20,21];
            var now = new Date();
            var hours = now.getHours();
              if (A.includes(hours)) {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('A');
            } else if (B.includes(hours)) {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('B');
            } else {
                jQuery('#top').addClass('C');
            }
        });
```